# How can i get this rendered canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, console.log, html2canvas

When i run this code in firefox console, i got the returned value undefined and open a blank page

```
    let m=$.getScript("https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js", function() {
html2canvas(document.querySelector("body > table.troisbords > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td > div > blockquote > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(2) > img"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                 var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        return myImage;
               },
                       allowTaint: true,
                    taintTest: false
         });
         }); 


m.then((value) => {
    console.log(value);
    window.open(value);
});
```

but the firefox console shows that there's a rendered canvas with the image i need

[check screenshot of the firefox console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miL3B.png)

How can i get that image please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

its actually the line

```
m.then((value) => {
   console.log(value);  //this line
   window.open(value);
});
```

it return canvas in order to convert the canvas in image you need `canvas.toDataUrl` i.e

```
let image = canvas.toDataUrl("image/png");
```

and then

```
window.open(image);
```

to show it in new tab

you can also show the image in new window in iframe i.e

```
var win = window.open();
win.document.write('<iframe src="' + image + '" frameborder="0" style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
```